# How to create dynamic body of XML using JMeter & Groovy Code

Tags: xml, groovy, jmeter

I'm trying to create a dynamic body of an XML using JMeter (with Groovy code as language) but every time I received the same error while running the script.
In which way can I solve my issue?

CODE:

```
 <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            ${listReleaseGroupTo}
 <!--Optional:-->
```

SCRIPT:

```
def numeroIterazioni = ${rowNumSalesOrder} // dynamic value, eg: 5

def releaseGroup = new StringBuilder()
upto(numeroIterazioni, { index ->
    releaseGroup.append(<to1:listReleaseGroupTO>)
    .append(<!--to1:backOrder>${BACK_ORDER_1}</to1:backOrder-->)
    .append(<!--to1:deliveryGroup>?</to1:deliveryGroup-->)
    .append(<!--to1:deliveryShift>${DELIVERY_SHIFT_1}</to1:deliveryShift-->)
    .append(<to1:homeWarehouse>${HOME_WAREHOUSE_CODE_1}</to1:homeWarehouse>)
    .append(<!--to1:numberOfOrders>1</to1:numberOfOrders-->)
    .append(<to1:orderNumber>${SALES_ORDER_CODE_${index}}</to1:orderNumber>)
    .append(<to1:orderType>${ORDER_TYPE_1}</to1:orderType>)
    .append(<!--to1:priority>${PRIORITY_1}</to1:priority-->)
    .append(<to1:supplyingWarehouse>${listSupplyingWarehouseCode}</to1:supplyingWarehouse>)
    .append(<!--to1:van>${VAN_CODE_1}</to1:van-->)
    .append(<to1:deliveryDate>${DELIVERY_DATE_1}</to1:deliveryDate>)
    .append(</to1:listReleaseGroupTO>)
})

vars.put('listReleaseGroupTo', releaseGroup.toString())
```

I want to create my dynamic body replacing the variable in "CODE" that is ${listReleaseGroupTo} with the code below, in "SCRIPT".
Thanks a lot!

I tried using 1.upto, deleting 1 or deleting all 1.upto, but it never works.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFtWQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid piece of Groovy code:

1. You can use [upto()](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Number.html#upto(java.lang.Number,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) only in conjunction with a Number, i.e. `1.upto(closure)`
2. Every item you're passing to [StringBuilder.append()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) function must be surrounded by quotation marks
3. Don't refer [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) as `${rowNumSalesOrder}`, use **vars** shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance instead

Example code:

```
def numeroIterazioni = vars.get('rowNumSalesOrder') as int

1.upto(numeroIterazioni, { index ->
    releaseGroup.append('<to1:listReleaseGroupTO>')
            .append('<!--to1:backOrder>').append(vars.get('BACK_ORDER_1')).append('</to1:backOrder-->')
            .append('<!--to1:deliveryGroup>?</to1:deliveryGroup-->')
            .append('<!--to1:deliveryShift>').append(vars.get('DELIVERY_SHIFT_1')).append('< /to1:deliveryShift-->')
            .append('<to1:homeWarehouse>').append(vars.get('HOME_WAREHOUSE_CODE_1')).append('</ to1: homeWarehouse > ')
    //etc
})
vars.put('listReleaseGroupTo', releaseGroup.toString())
```

Going forward if something "never works" take a look at [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

And last but not the least, you're creating text string, not XML, maybe you're looking for [MarkupBuilder](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_creating_xml) instead?

Comment: Hi Dimitri T, thanks for your answer!
I've resolved some issues, but now I've a trouble with the index, I thought that it was the counter of my iteration, but if I want to put inside some tags, it's not written as the number that I thinks it will be, but with the word 'index', if I write as index, as ${index} or vars.get(index).
Could you explain me why? Thanks again!